# Access property of a PHP object

Tags: php

I'm passing in an object using an ajax function. The object looks like this:

`{"label":"1","number":2}`

Once the object reaches the server I'm using PHP to `json_decode` it.

After it's decoded how can I start accessing the properties of the object? For example I want to retrieve the value of `label` - how can this be done?

Comment: If only there was some online resource which one could access wiht helpful documentation somewhere. Something like a manual of some sorts. That would be totally awesome right?

Answer (score 3):

```
$myobj = json_decode($JSON);
print $myojb->label;
```

You might want to read about [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in the manual. An alternative syntax would be decoding the JSON to an array and then accessing it via the key.

```
$myarr = json_decode($JSON, TRUE);
print $myarr['label'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access it like this;

```
$json = json_decode($input);
echo $json->label;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input=json_decode(your json);
echo $input->label;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way....

from jquery..

```
  var a= {'label':'1','number':'2'};
   $.ajax({       
       data : {data:JSON.stringify(a)},
   })
```

from php side

```
   if(isset($_POST['data']))
   {
        $data = $_POST['data'];
        $data = json_decode($data,true);
        echo $data['label']; //will print label here
   }
```

this is full example of ajax request with json to php...

might help you...

Comment: There's an error in your syntax `{'label:'1'` should be `{'label':'1'`